# Throwing null pointer exception in Android

Tags: java, android, audio, arraylist, audio-player, android-music-player

I'm trying to fetch an audio file from the audio directory, for that I'm using below code. I'm not able to figure out why this condition `if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0)` is throwing an error. Code is given below.

```
Uri allsongsuri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
final String MEDIA_PATH = allsongsuri.toString();
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList(){
    System.out.println(" -- "+MEDIA_PATH);
    File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);

    if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) {
        for (File file : home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) {
            HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
        song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));
            song.put("songPath", file.getPath());

            // Adding each song to SongList
        songsList.add(song);
        }
    }
    return songsList;
}

class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
    return (name.endsWith(".mp3") || name.endsWith(".MP3"));
}
```

I need to store audio file in ArrayList using hashMap. I tried this example to store file in List
    http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/02/list-audio-media-in-mediastoreaudiomedi.html . Using this example I tried a lot to store the list in ArrayList as my reqirement need that. But didn't succeed. 
    I need help. I have to store Audio file in Arraylist.

Comment: Show us the stack trace and highlight the line number where you get the NPE please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class SongsManager {
    final String MEDIA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getPath() + "/";
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    private String mp3Pattern = ".mp3";

    // Constructor
    public SongsManager() {

    }

    /**
     * Function to read all mp3 files and store the details in
     * ArrayList
     * */
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList() {
        System.out.println(MEDIA_PATH);
        if (MEDIA_PATH != null) {
            File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
            File[] listFiles = home.listFiles();
            if (listFiles != null && listFiles.length > 0) {
                for (File file : listFiles) {
                    System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        scanDirectory(file);
                    } else {
                        addSongToList(file);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // return songs list array
        return songsList;
    }

    private void scanDirectory(File directory) {
        if (directory != null) {
            File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();
            if (listFiles != null && listFiles.length > 0) {
                for (File file : listFiles) {
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        scanDirectory(file);
                    } else {
                        addSongToList(file);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void addSongToList(File song) {
        if (song.getName().endsWith(mp3Pattern)) {
            HashMap<String, String> songMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            songMap.put("songTitle",
                    song.getName().substring(0, (song.getName().length() - 4)));
            songMap.put("songPath", song.getPath());

            // Adding each song to SongList
            songsList.add(songMap);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: we can use FilenameFilter instead of addSongToList methode!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't forget the uses permission READ EXTERNAL STORAGE in manifest.xml

Comment: I also had to add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to my manifest file. In addition, it's necessary to prompt the user to accept file system permissions or have the user manually approve these permissions in settings.

Answer (score 0):

This must be `home.listFiles` returning `null`.

From [Android developer reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) on `public File[] listFiles (FileFilter filter)`

> Gets a list of the files in the directory represented by this file. This list is then filtered through a FileFilter and matching files are returned as an array of files. **Returns null if this file is not a directory.** If filter is null then all files match.

So you need to make sure that `MEDIA_PATH` is a proper directory.

Comment: Yes @Szymon, It was home.listFiles which was returning null.

Answer (score 0):

The "listFiles()" method can return null if the file is not found. I would suggest putting in a check to see if it's null first, and only proceed if it is something other than null. Example:

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList(){
    System.out.println(" -- "+MEDIA_PATH);
    File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);

    if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()) != null){
        if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) {
            for (File file : home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) {
                HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
                song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));
                song.put("songPath", file.getPath());

                // Adding each song to SongList
                songsList.add(song);
            }
        }
    }

    return songsList;
}
```

You will probably want to put in an else statement as well, in order to make sure that songsList is not null when it is returned.

Comment: Thanks All for giving your valuable time... I got it working in little different way.. Pasting code here so that It can be usefull for someone else... Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

with ref to Anup's and Destrom's answer I just want put the code with with Filename Filter

```
    public class SongsManager {
    // SDCard Path
//  final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/sdcard/sound_recorder"); 

    final String MEDIA_PATH =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/sound_recorder";
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Constructor
    public SongsManager(){

    }

    /**
     * Function to read all mp3 files from sdcard
     * and store the details in ArrayList
     * */
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList(){

        Log.d("testsd",MEDIA_PATH);
        File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);

    //  if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) //don't use this to avoid null pointer exception !
        if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())!=null) {
            for (File file : home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) {
                HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();


                song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));
                song.put("songPath", file.getPath());

                // Adding each song to SongList


                songsList.add(song);

            }
        }
        // return songs list array
        return songsList;
    }

    /**
     * Class to filter files which are having .mp3 extension
     * */
    class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return (name.endsWith(".mp3") || name.endsWith(".MP3") || name.endsWith(".3gpp") || name.endsWith(".wav")); //add more extensions here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lote.....was getting mat with the moto g without a sdcard.....it emulate the physical sdcard....still not work.

But your code work perfect with another motorola that has the physical sdcard

i mean when the sdcard is emulated dontwork  ..i try all the MEDIA_PATHS possibles

i need your advice...thanks.
//final String MEDIA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +   "/";
    //private final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/sdcard/res/raw/");
    //final String MEDIA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +   "/";
    //final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/sdcard/");
    //final String MEDIA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +   "/";
//  final String MEDIA_PATH ="";
    //final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/sdcard/Musica/");
    //final String MEDIA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +   "/";
    //final String  MEDIAPATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +   "/Musica/";
    //final String MEDIAPATH = new String("/sdcard/");
    //final String MEDIA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +   "/";
    final String MEDIA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/";

Comment: This should really be asked as its own question.  Since its not an answer and you dont have the rep to post it as a comment, its the only wway it wil be seen