# force close on android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, forceclose

the code get music files from sdcard/music and view list of theme

in android 5 force close occur

I think the problem is this function

FileExtensionFilter()

```
package com.ghs.musicsatsametime;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class SongsManager {
    // SDCard Path
    final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/sdcard/Music");
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Constructor
    public SongsManager(){

    }

    /**
     * Function to read all mp3 files from sdcard
     * and store the details in ArrayList
     * */
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList(){
        File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);

        if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) {
            for (File file : home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) {
                HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
                song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));
                song.put("songPath", file.getPath());

                // Adding each song to SongList
                songsList.add(song);
            }
        }
        // return songs list array
        return songsList;
    }

    /**
     * Class to filter files which are having .mp3 extension
     * */
    class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return (name.endsWith(".mp3") || name.endsWith(".MP3"));
        }
    }
}
```

and my logcat

```
10-30 10:45:30.176: E/AndroidRuntime(15788): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-30 10:45:30.176: E/AndroidRuntime(15788): Process: com.ghs.musicsatsametime, PID: 15788
10-30 10:45:30.176: E/AndroidRuntime(15788): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
10-30 10:45:30.176: E/AndroidRuntime(15788):    at com.ghs.musicsatsametime.SongsManager.getPlayList(SongsManager.java:25)
10-30 10:45:30.176: E/AndroidRuntime(15788):    at com.ghs.musicsatsametime.dj.DJMusicFragment.getMusicList(DJMusicFragment.java:421)
10-30 10:45:30.176: E/AndroidRuntime(15788):    at com.ghs.musicsatsametime.dj.DJMusicFragment.access$22(DJMusicFragment.java:415)
10-30 10:45:30.176: E/AndroidRuntime(15788):    at com.ghs.musicsatsametime.dj.DJMusicFragment$7.onClick(DJMusicFragment.java:359)
10-30 10:45:30.176: E/AndroidRuntime(15788):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4856)
10-30 10:45:30.176: E/AndroidRuntime(15788):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19956)
10-30 10:45:30.176: E/AndroidRuntime(15788):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
10-30 10:45:30.176: E/AndroidRuntime(15788):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-30 10:45:30.176: E/AndroidRuntime(15788):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
10-30 10:45:30.176: E/AndroidRuntime(15788):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
10-30 10:45:30.176: E/AndroidRuntime(15788):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-30 10:45:30.176: E/AndroidRuntime(15788):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-30 10:45:30.176: E/AndroidRuntime(15788):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:945)
10-30 10:45:30.176: E/AndroidRuntime(15788):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:740)
```

Comment: Post your logcat, please.

Comment: Exception StackTrace would be helpful

Comment: Attempt to get length of null array is the error.

Comment: Just some code improvement, you don't have to check if your array length is greater 0, since you are iterating over each item in your loop. To prevent your NPE you should check if it is null.

Comment: Also, since any programmer needs to be able to analyze a callstack, rather than just asking for help on this particular error and how to solve it, you should *really* try to look at your log and try to understand what happens and why. As you can see, call stacks are very informative, stating the line number where the error occured and what the problem was (in this case, trying to call `length()` on a null instance of an array).

Comment: Oh, and please try to be more informative in your problem descriptions. The title "force close on lollipop" could apply to virtually millions of different programming errors, it says nothing about your particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the following permission to your AndroidManifest.xml?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

External storage read access is required to list files in a directory.

Answer (score 0):

Based on you log, which says:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
```

I found this line in your code:

```
 if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) {
```

The listFiles() methods returns a null array. It didn't event init or alloced. Thus,  I guess a little protection on this line would help this crash:

```
 List<File> files = home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter());
 if (null != files && files.length > 0) {
    for(File file:files){
       ...
     }
 }
```

this line will pretect code from crashing , but I don't know whether this line returns the correct array you need. Is this crash happened when there is no file under this path?

update: thx @JHH's suggestion

Comment: And @Neil's answer is also a very important part needs to be checked.

Comment: Not very efficient to run the code twice, and creating *two* filter objects. In this case, declaring and assigning a local variable the value of `listFiles()`, *then* null-checking and length-checking it, would be nicer.

Answer (score 0):

You variable home is null.

> Gets a list of the files in the directory represented by this file.
>   This list is then filtered through a FileFilter and matching files are
>   returned as an array of files. **Returns null if this file is not a
>   directory**. If filter is null then all files match.

See here: [Throwing null pointer exception in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20022439/throwing-null-pointer-exception-in-android)

My first guess is you don't have any permissions.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you should try that: put "Music" folder into your phone storage ("Device storage"). The log showed that your file path is wrong so listFiles() return null

```
final String MEDIA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Music/");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all

the problem solved

I changed

```
home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0
```

to

```
home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length != 0
```